# Unexpected string when outputting textfile

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, node.js

I have some data I'm trying to output to an output text file. This is how I am trying to do that:

```
'use strict';
var fs = require('fs');

let id = require('./ID.json');
let obj = require('./dataOut.json');
let isp = require('./isp');
let dst = require('./dst');
let dst_lat = require('./dst_lat');
let dst_lng = require('./dst_lng');

const output = [];
let i = 0;

obj.forEach(block => {
    let outputOut = 
        '    {\n',
        '      "_id": ' + '"' + id[i] + '",\n',
        '      "latlng": [\n',
        '        ' + dst_lat[i] + ',\n',
        '        ' + dst_lng[i] + '\n',
        '       ],\n',
        '       "name":' + '"' + isp[i] + '",\n',
        '       "address":' + '"' + dst[i] + '"\n',
        '},\n';
        output.push(outputOut);
    i++;
});
fs.writeFile('./output.json');
```

I want the data to look exactly how it appears in the variable *outputOut*, however, when I run this code I run into the error *unexpected string*.

I understand why I'm running into this error, but I cannot think of a way to resolve it.

How can I save my *outputOut* data to a textfile?

Comment: Why are you building the json manually with strings? You may be misunderstanding `JSON.stringify`. It takes a javascript object or a valid JSON object and returns the string version of that. Your string concatenation is overkill and unnecessary. Try building an object instead.

Comment: hi @Seth, I probably should of removed the json.Stringify from this post. I'll edit it. As for building an object instead, I should, but I wanted to know if this method is possible.

Comment: At the end `outputOut` has a value `'},\n';`. See, [how Comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator) works.

Comment: @Teemu thanks for the response, but that comma is intentional, I want it in the text

Comment: But it is not a part of the string in your code. Maybe you'd need a [Template string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)?

Comment: String concatenation in javascript is done with `+`, not `,`

Comment: you're doing it all wrong. `JSON.stringify(theobject,null,2)` never build json by hand... if you need to append to an existing json file, read the file, parse it, modify it, and re-write it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may be misunderstanding [`JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify). It takes a javascript object or a valid JSON object and returns the string version of that. Your string concatenation is unnecessary. Secondly, you're actually concatenating `outputOut` incorrectly. Concatenation in done like so: `var saying = "Hello" + "World";`

Try building an object instead:

```
'use strict';
const fs = require('fs');

const id = require('./ID.json');
const obj = require('./dataOut.json');
const isp = require('./isp');
const dst = require('./dst');
const dst_lat = require('./dst_lat');
const dst_lng = require('./dst_lng');

const output = [];
let i = 0;

obj.forEach(block => {
    let outputOut = {
      "_id": id[i],
      "latlng": [
        dst_lat[i],
        dst_lng[i],
      ],
      "name": isp[i],
      "address": dst[i],
    }

    output.push(outputOut);
    i++;
});

fs.writeFile('./output.json', JSON.stringify(output, null, 2), 'utf-8');
```

This approach is much more idiomatic and simpler. Additionally it's easier to read. Let JavaScript do the heavy lifting for you, rather than writing complex code which still may achieve the same results but at a much higher cost.

Lastly, a more functional approach would be to use [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```
'use strict';
const fs = require('fs');

const id = require('./ID.json');
const obj = require('./dataOut.json');
const isp = require('./isp');
const dst = require('./dst');
const dst_lat = require('./dst_lat');
const dst_lng = require('./dst_lng');

const output = obj.map((block, i) => {
  return {
    "_id": id[i],
    "latlng": [
      dst_lat[i],
      dst_lng[i],
    ],
    "name": isp[i],
    "address": dst[i],
  };
});

fs.writeFile('./output.json', JSON.stringify(output, null, 2), 'utf-8');
```

This approach avoids the need to mutate `output` with each iteration as well as leverages the index within the callback function instead of incrementing a counter var.

Comment: I misunderstood how this method would look in the output, I didn't realize I could do it this way. Thank you, this makes much more sense, and it much clearer than what I was doing.

Comment: Updated the answer with a cleaner approach for you @Bryce. This will reduce your lines of code and variables a bit.

Answer (score 1):

As I see you try to create a JSON text by yourself. The problem is that you did not concatenate the string parts, but used a comma expression (and did not put it in brackets. If you did so, it would still be flawed, because the comma expression will not concatenate the string, but keep the last one).

One thing to remember: Dont try to create your own JSON form strings. People already did it for you. All you have to do is a proper mapping of those objects, and call `JSON.stringify`:

```
'use strict';
var fs = require('fs');

let id = require('./ID.json');
let obj = require('./dataOut.json');
let isp = require('./isp');
let dst = require('./dst');
let dst_lat = require('./dst_lat');
let dst_lng = require('./dst_lng');

const output = obj.map((block, i) => {
  return {
    _id: id[i],
    latlng: [
      dst_lat[i],
      dst_lng[i]
    ],
    name: isp[i],
    address: dst[i]
  };
});

fs.writeFile('./output.json', JSON.stringify(output, null, 2), 'utf-8');
```

Answer (score 1):

**Apart from the wrong approach you are using**, if you want to concatenate a string in javascript, you need to use `+`, not `,`

```
let outputOut =
    '    {\n' +
    '      "_id": ' + '"' + id[i] + '",\n' +
    '      "latlng": [\n' +
    '        ' + dst_lat[i] + ',\n' +
    '        ' + dst_lng[i] + '\n' +
    '       ],\n' +
    '       "name":' + '"' + isp[i] + '",\n' +
    '       "address":' + '"' + dst[i] + '"\n' +
    '},\n';
output.push(outputOut);
```

That's where your error comes from.

**Other answers already posted will show you the correct way of doing what you want to do**

Comment: Downvoter, with which part of the answer do you disagree?

Comment: Not the downvoter speaking, but the implementation (manual JSON string building) shouldn't be expounded upon. It's not a practice one should use or condone. Alternative approaches should be used since the OP didn't specify that they needed string concatenation.

Comment: @baao this was the answer I needed originally, thank you very much. I decided to go with Seth's solution for the reasons above, however I learned something from your post as well. thanks!

Comment: You should go with his solution, yes! @Bryce

Comment: @Seth yeah. That's why I wrote that to my answer - and +1 you... But I think it's good to show the actual error someone made.. I bolded the important parts... :-)